# How can I require the module into my file?

Tags: node.js, express

I create an express project and the directory structure like:

```
/
  - model
    db.js
  - routes
    users.js
  app.js
```

In ./model/db.js, I have a MySql connection:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'root',
database : 'imei_node'
});

connection.connect();
```

And in ./routes/users.js, I need to query database:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require('./model/db.js');   // always cannot find the module....

router.route('/')
.get(function (req, res) {
    connection.query(
        'select * from user',
        function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send('error');
            } else {
                res.send({
                    result      : 'success',
                    err         : '',
                    err_type    : '',
                    fields      : fields,
                    rows        : rows,
                    length      : rows.length
                });
            }
        }
    )
});


module.exports = router;
```

But the debugger always says that Cannot find the module './model/db.js'.

I am new to nodejs, can anybody tell me how to require the db.js into routes file? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `require('../model/db.js')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` refers to the current directory, while `../` refers to a parent directory.

From `/routes/users.js` you are trying to require `./model/db.js` which is trying to find a file in `/routes/model/db.js`.

Try changing this to `var connection = require('../model/db.js');`

Also, it's worth noting that you don't need to include `.js`, Node will append this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require('../model/db.js');   // the module....

router.route('/')
.get(function (req, res) {
    connection.query(
        'select * from user',
        function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send('error');
            } else {
                res.send({
                    result      : 'success',
                    err         : '',
                    err_type    : '',
                    fields      : fields,
                    rows        : rows,
                    length      : rows.length
                });
            }
        }
    )
});


module.exports = router;
```